# Transfer of material properties with subsequent separation

Tags: materials

How can I assign the material of the first sphere to the second and third sphere, and then change their properties (for example, the color) independently?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To give the material of sphere 1 to sphere 2 and 3, a quick way is to select 2 and 3, shift select 1 at last, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Materials*. Now they all have the same material.

If you  want to change a parameter for one sphere, like a different color, you have no other choice than to create a brand new material:

[image]

If you still want some parameters of the materials to be linked you can try it through node groups. Node groups can be shared between several materials. For example if you want to keep the same *Principled BSDF* between several materials, and only change the color, plug a *Color > Gamma* node into the Base Color of the *Principled BSDF*, select the *Principled BSDF*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to access or exit from the group. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to ungroup. To bring an existing node group in another material, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Group > NodeGroup*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!

Comment: Stupid question: if you would just want to change the color, why not use an _Input_ > _RGB_ node instead of a _Gamma_ node?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's any difference

Comment: For the result it doesn't make a difference, but of course the _Gamma_ node serves a very different purpose beyond just choosing a color, so I thought you picked that node intentional.

Comment: So what would be the main purpose of each of these nodes?

Comment: The _RGB_ node simply outputs a color and has no input. The _Gamma_ node can use a color, a texture or an image etc. as input and then you can change the gamma value to vary the output of the texture or image. And therre is a _Gamma_ input as well, which means you cannot simply change the value evenly for the whole image but plug a gradient or texture in there, too.

Comment: OK, I've never had the opportunity to use the Gamma actually, rather the Bright/Contrast for example